# Enable MSI Logging with WIX by default

Tags: logging, wix, installation, windows-installer

I am currently writing an installer for my software, and would really like to log the install. I am using Wix. However, the only ways i have seen to log the install are to change the reg (as a global setting) and add it as a command from the command line using /l*v or something similar.
what I would like to do, is log, as soon as the installer is run, only for that installer, without modifying the registry key for that single install.
Is there anyway i can do this or something close to this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [MsiLogging property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370322(v=vs.85).aspx)

The problem is it's only available starting with MSI 4.0.  There's also a bug in Windows 7 where sometimes uninstall from Add/Remove programs will fail because explorer loses where the temp directory is.  Additionally it creates Msiabcxyz.log (abcxyz is some random hash) in the TEMP directory that can be hard for users to identify.

You could also wrap the MSI in an EXE bootstrapper and pass the logging flags in that way. It can fail though if the path (directory) doesn't exist.

All in all, I wouldn't bother.  Create a .bat file that calls the install with logging for your testing and only enable logging in production when there is a problem.  Otherwise it just slows your install down.

Comment: Thats useful! didnt realise about the bug in Win7. The downside is that when its in the field, the first i would hear about it is when someone complains it doesnt install.. a log would be helpful on the occasion it did. Still, youre right, i should be optimistic and expect no issues (no logging)!

Comment: A lot of companies just write a KB article on logging the install and contacting support.  Here's the KB on the Win7 bug: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2564571   PS- accepted answers are appreciated.

Comment: I was going to accept when i was sure i understood! ;) honest guv'
Thanks for the help, much appreciated (and the links etc)