# wix install report from a MSI

Tags: wix

When you use Installshield you get a install report summary for all the files and components. How do you get a report in wix? Below is a example of what I am looking for that I get with install shield

```
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////// Summary //////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            Components:                     19
            File Groups:                    20
            Number of Files:               364
            Size of Files:           365208904
            Size in Library:         241120877



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////// File Groups ////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

>Program DLLs<

        Size of Files:            33579481
        Size in Library:           8542805


        File                                                    Date        Time      Size         Version            Attributes    MD5                                     Source file
        ------------------------------------------------------  ----------  --------  -----------  -----------------  ------------  --------------------------------------  ------------------------------------------------
        "workgroupcommunicationsud.dll"                         6/23/2015 4:33:44 AM       368740  "5.2.0.12"         "A"           "b7e5ba6b-704e-5f61-8b41-abb2a1d00c47"  "..\bin\workgroupcommunicationsud.dll"
        "aucommunicatorps.dll"                                  6/23/2015 4:36:16 AM        28672  "5.2.0.12"         "A"           "a0e65f49-4486-103c-29cd-ceda381407f7"  "..\bin\aucommunicatorps.dll"
        "bmpmgrud.dll"                                          6/23/2015 4:35:28 AM       114771  "5.2.0.12"         "A"           "a2281454-3138-8edb-e6d0-924119179b69"  "..\bin\bmpmgrud.dll"
        "btcputilitiesd.dll"                                    6/23/2015 4:33:28 AM       159833  "5.2.0.12"         "A"           "77278c22-5166-b9a9-21f9-df34fae39a19"  "..\bin\btcputilitiesd.dll"
        "businessmodelud.dll"                                   6/23/2015 4:35:14 AM     11038810  "5.2.0.12"         "A"           "03681184-77c8-4ec1-df81-9102e7fd7b76"  "..\bin\businessmodelud.dll"
        "cdrvdl32.dll"                                          6/23/2015 4:15:16 AM        31232  "17.0.0.0"         "R"           "cb939299-b6b7-3595-736e-cabd5ea7b007"  "..\bin\cdrvdl32.dll"
        "cdrvhf32.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Seen those before. We even ran the installers on a clean machine and fed the logs into a database. The things is, now that we don't get them, we don't need them. Maybe you'll come the same conclusion.

See, an MSI is a database. You can query it with the Windows Installer API. WiX provides a library called DTF that wraps the API in a .NET library.

On a particular machine, Windows Installer keeps a database of installed components and the features of versioned products that reference the components. Again, you can use the API with or without DTF to query that database.

If you happen to want to know what a particular Windows Installer operation does, you can configure logging for that operation on the command or toggle logging for all operations in the Windows registry. (Don't forget to turn it off later.) Or, you can configure logging for a particular MSI by [setting a property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27965610/2226988) in it. See [this page](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm) for a rundown on all of these techniques. The Windows Installer documentation is the definitive guide.